# Printing the probability when a die rolls all 6 sides

Tags: python, probability, dice

I am trying to print the expected amount of when a fair die is rolled and to keep rolling until all 6 sides are rolled.

What I am trying to do is when as an example a `1` is rolled it is added to a list. Then to keep going till all 6 sides are rolled and using `count+=1` to keep rolling the next die and use count as the number of times. Then once the list equals `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` to make stop equal True and to break.

But should I use a shift method so if 3 is found then you delete it from the list?

Then once done at the end I want to compute the expected amount of rolls using `count`

```
import random
def rolldice():
    count = 0
    while True:
        die = []
        win = []
        for i in range(1):
            die.append(random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
        stop = False
        for roll in die:
            number = die.count(roll)
            if(number == 1):
                win += [1]
            if(number == 2):
                win += [2]
            if(number == 3):
                win += [3]
            if(number == 4):
                win += [4]
            if(number == 5):
                win += [5]
            if(number == 6):
                win += [6]
            if(win == [1,2,3,4,5,6]):
                stop = True
                break
        if stop:
            break
        else:
            count += 1
    print(f'Count is {count}')
def main():
    rolldice()
main()
```

Trying to see if I am on the right track or if I should use shifting and deleting.

Comment: You are trying to find the probability of _what_?

Comment: My guess is that you want to keep track of the frequencies and then compute what the probability is from that distribution. Is that correct?

Comment: Or is it the expected number of rolls required before all six sides are rolled?

Comment: If you keep rolling, you will eventually roll all six numbers, so the _probability_ is one.  What are you _actually_ trying to do here?

Comment: I want to compute the probability of how many times it takes to roll a fair die until all 6 sides are rolled hence why I said to equal ```[1,2,3,4,5,6]```

Comment: `if(win == [1,2,3,4,5,6])` Even if all six numbers have been rolled, they likely weren't rolled in that exact order, so this statement will be false.

Comment: _I want to compute the probability of how many times it takes_ That's not **probability**; that's **expected number of rolls**.

Comment: It seems his function is just calculating how many times it took to roll all 6 sides, not the expected number of rolls.

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry thought it meant probability by what the question said. So then if thats not possible would it be better-using shifting and deletion?

Comment: @LoMaPh Yea thats what I am trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to count how many rolls it takes to get all six sides, using a set is much easier:

```
import random

# initialize to empty set
results = set()

# remember how many rolls we have made
rolls = 0

# keep going until we roll all six sides
while len(results) != 6:
    rolls += 1
    results.add(random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6]))

print('It took %d rolls to get all six sides' % rolls)
```

Comment: Ahh I see what you did there it's way simpler.  I was just trying to add it into a list and then once all 6 sides were in that list then to break and count the number of times it took to get all 6 sides.